# How to use a local GeoJSON file with Mapbox in React

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

Good day,

I am using Mapbox in React to make a map with a polygon layer. The issue is that I have to use a **local** GeoJSON file for the polygon layer and I **cannot use a URL**. I have seen some solutions, but none in React.

Here is the code with the URL that works:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactMapboxGL, { Source, Layer } from "react-map-gl";

class Mapbox extends Component {
  state = {
    viewport: {
      width: "100vw",
      height: "90vh",
      latitude: 44.065256,
      longitude: -125.075801,
      zoom: 4,
    },
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Mapbox">
        <ReactMapboxGL
          {...this.state.viewport}
          onViewportChange={(viewport) => this.setState({ viewport })}
          mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11"
          mapboxApiAccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoiY2FybGF2ZGIiLCJhIjoiY2o0ZTM3d293MHRraTMydWZ5aGVtajdldSJ9.BMk1gf9OXguMOhEqcP43eg"
        >
          <Source
            id="oregonjson"
            type="geojson"
#Here is the URL:
            data="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glynnbird/usstatesgeojson/master/oregon.geojson"
          />
          <Layer
            id="anything"
            type="fill"
            source="oregonjson"
            paint={{ "fill-color": "#228b22", "fill-opacity": 0.4 }}
          />
        </ReactMapboxGL>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Mapbox;
```

The local file's name is "oregon_local.geojson" and is exactly the same as the URL.

Instead of the URL, I have tried:

```
<Source
    id="oregonjson"
    type="geojson"
    data={require("../diagrams/oregon_local.geojson")}
/>
```

This gives an error:

```
Error {message: "Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object."}
```

I have also tried:

```
<Source
     id="oregonjson"
     type="geojson"
     data={"file://D:/diagrams/oregon_local.geojson"}
/>
```

This gives the error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

I also tried:

```
<Source
   id="oregonjson"
   type="geojson"
   data={"http://../diagrams/oregon_local.geojson"}
/>
```

This gives the error:

```
Error {message: "Failed to fetch"}
```

**How can I load a local GeoJSON as a polygon layer using Mapbox in React?**

[Here is a link to the Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mapbox-in-react-h8vmn?file=/src/diagrams/oregon_local.geojson:14709-14742)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in couple ways.

#### - Import geojson in react

Change geojson file extension to `json`

```js
import oregon_local from './assets/oregon.json'
...
<Source id="oregonjson" type="geojson" data={oregon_local} >
...
```

This way is ok if your geojson file file is rather small, because it will be bundled into your javascript.

#### - Use mapbox data loading

Place your geojson file in public/data folder

```js
<Source type="geojson" data="/data/oregon.geojson" >
...
```